# Quorum allowing ethereum addresses

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, quorum

I would like to ask how is it possible to register patients for example using Quorum . I am using solidity. When I am using the public Ethereum blockchain, I usually make a registration smart contract and add patients addresses in a mapping with a boolean. Then I check the value of the boolean before executing the functions to ensure that those addresses are allowed and registered. How can I do this in a private Ehtereum blockchain? Is it done in the same way? Can I simply make a smart contract like I do in a public blockchain? or is it done by an entity when designing the network ... like a membership service provider in Hyperledger fabric?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's possible to run smart contract on private Ethereum chains. So you would be able to run a smart contract the same way as you do on the public chain.

However, I'm not very familiar with Quorum or Hyperledger fabric. So maybe they allow for a simpler way to manage users that is built into their solution, and someone else will come up with more accurate answer.